# Why do Hotmail & Gmail mark all emails as spam for no clear reason?

Tags: email-server, spam, exim, gmail

Been testing for **DKIM**, **SPF**, **DMRC** and all of them are valid. Proven over several online tools. 
*mail-tester.com* gave 8.8 points.

Server is not blacklisted anywhere, so far I checked.

But no matter what content (html or plaintext) I send gmail delivers it to recipient's spambox and hotmail not even accepting it.

I'm desperately no idea why this happens. Please could you give any suggestion.

My server runs exim with dovecot and opendkim.

Following are the headers from latest sent (marked as spam) email

[image]

Comment: I sometimes have the same problem, even with correct SPF/DKIM/DMARC configuration. My idea is that if you're not a big e-mail provider, your reputation is lowered, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the reverse DNS PTR from your server's IP does not forward resolve to the same IP address (FCrDNS) - our mail system would reject because of this as the rDNS looks fake.

You should also use a third level host name instead of the second level domain name, e.g. `mail.domain.tld` instead of `domain.tld` since your 2nd level domain is likely to resolve to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem time ago and was for use greylisting. Seems that this providers are changing the IP from smtp when sends the email and how you marks how spam they do the same. Can you publish config used for spam? 
The solution was easy, use a whitelist with pool IPs from gmail and hotmail smtps.

Comment: you mean exim.conf ?

Comment: server wide spam assassin is used to check incoming and outgoing email

Answer (score 0):

Well even with white listed IP addresses , and with a well configured mail server (DNS, RDNS, SPF, DKIM, And maybe Dmarc aswell), your IP addresses need to gain reputation , that means that you have to warm your IPs, and get alot of positive feedback (Open your mails, and not move it to junk) from your subscribers.

With hotmail there is what it's called SNDS -Smart Network Data Service- that you can use to see and to have a clear Idea about your IP addresses Reputation.