# Gmail detects emails as spam from domain with neutral reputation

Tags: email, spam, gmail, spam-filter, spam-marked

I have a new domain and mail-in-a-box server set up correctly. Unfortunately, when sending to Gmail, it treats emails from my domain a a spam.

The domain is not blacklisted and DNS settings are also correct. I checked it using www.mail-tester.com and it shows score 10/10. I did not send any mass emails and just sent several test emails only. So my domain definitely should not be treated as spam.

The only thing that I noticed that my domain has NEUTRAL rating. I heard that gmail could mark emails coming from domains with NEUTRAL rating as spam. Is it true, have you faced with the similar issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: checked this? https://serverfault.com/questions/862613/why-do-hotmail-gmail-mark-all-emails-as-spam-for-no-clear-reason

Comment: Thanks, I saw the similar message to "Well even with white listed IP addresses , and with a well configured mail server (DNS, RDNS, SPF, DKIM, And maybe Dmarc aswell), your IP addresses need to gain reputation , that means that you have to warm your IPs, and get alot of positive feedback (Open your mails, and not move it to junk) from your subscribers.". But how can I get the positive feed back from gmail users if my emails are already considered as spam? Should a lot of users press 'Not spam' button to gain  reputation?

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple you got an IP reputation which is based on how and when do you things send. Google rejects your mails because something is clearly missing.

The current requirements are **tls encrypted transfer**, **DKIM**, **SPF** and a valid **PTR record**.
Read more about it in the [bulk sender guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) of Google.

Please ensure that all of these requirements are met. After a while you will be fine with sending mails to Google which are not identified as spam.
There are also a few more things to do to ensure that mail delivery is nearly perfect but its a long way - to much to tell in short.

Comment: i find they are less picky for connections over ipv6 (with PTR), if that's an option